# How do i save a python dictionary with numpy arrays?

Tags: python

So if I make a dictionary like

```
dictionary = {'first': array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'second': array([1,2,3,4,5])}
```

and then if have to somehow save it to a file, how do I do it?
I tried pickling but it take a long time to pack and unpack the data at the start and end of the program as I am going to use a big dataset.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` is much faster

```
import numpy as np
dictionary = {'first': array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'second': array([1,2,3,4,5])}

# to save
np.save('data.npy', dictionary)

# to load
dictionary = np.load('data.npy')
```

Comment: when I load it again, its shows as an ndarray and now i cant use it as a dictionary and and use .keys(), .values(), etc. also I cant typecast it back into a dict when I load it again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary then use the dictionary to create a dataframe then call the to_csv method

```
dictionary = {'first': [1,2,3,4,5], 'second': [1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using pandas to_csv function to save it into a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
dictionary = {'first': np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), 'second': np.array([1,2,3,4,5])}
pd.DataFrame(dictionary).to_csv('data.csv')
```